# DB.collection('comments').find() not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, find

**findOne()**

```
const solutionList =  await CommentMicroserviceDB.collection('comments').findOne({organizationId: ObjectId('5eb393ee95fab7468a79d189')});
```

Working Fine:-

```
 { 
    _id: 6364e934830dcc00b488848d,
    type: 'DOUBTS',
    typeId: 63622eb7ddf697001fdc7b0a,
    organizationId: 5eb393ee95fab7468a79d189,
    createdBy: 62d53063e34fe92f8a135818,
    status: 'Active',
    displayOrder: 2,
    createdAt: 2022-11-02T09:27:25.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-11-02T09:27:25.000Z,
    text:'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n</head>\n<body>\n<p>Notification beofer berrnern</p>\n</body>\n</html>' 
}
```

**find()**

```
const solutionList =  await CommentMicroserviceDB.collection('comments').find({organizationId: ObjectId('5eb393ee95fab7468a79d189')});
```

But when I try with **find()** function is not working and give me:-

```
 Cursor {
 pool: null,
 server: null,
 disconnectHandler: Store { s: [Object], length: [Getter] },
 bson: BSON {},
 ns: 'comment_service.comments',
 cmd:
 { find: 'comment_service.comments',
 limit: 0,
 skip: 0,
 slaveOk: true },
 options:
 { readPreference: [ReadPreference],
   skip: 0,
   limit: 0,
   topology: [Server] },
 .....
 .....
 sortValue: undefined }
```

***Why this is happening ?***
findOne function is working perfectly but find not
i need find here because i need all docs with given organizationId

Can anyone tell me
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection.find()` returns a Cursor which is A pointer to the result set of a query. Clients can iterate through a cursor to retrieve results.

Refer to official [collection.find() documentation.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find)

If you just want the array of documents, try appending `.toArray()` at the end of your find query.

**Try this:**

```
const solutionList =  await CommentMicroserviceDB.collection('comments').find({
    organizationId: ObjectId('5eb393ee95fab7468a79d189')
}).toArray();
```

Read more about `.toArray()` [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)